# Image is not displaying in rails pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to display images in pdf. But it is not working.

The images are stored in upload_files folder which is outside app folder.

syntax used in html: `<%= image_tag impact_level.image_url(:small) %>`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is the HTML getting the correct URL for the PDF? What happens if you try to access that URL? You need to add more detail to your question. You can do that by editing it.

Comment: html is get the correcting url. but converting html to pdf the image is not displaying. The pdf preview page is coming correctly.

Comment: please note the image folder(upload_files) is not inside the app folder.